# Using a single dag on multiple inputs in Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, airflow

I'm trying to implement a pipeline in Airflow that will be run many times on many different input files. I want to submit a bunch of these jobs to AWS so they can run in parallel.

Can Airflow handle the scheduling and submission for this? (and what's the efficient Airflow way of doing it?)

Comment: Can you clarify on what service you need to run on AWS? do you mean input files with same format or they are different?